# iOS: How to move an image inside a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have an `UIImageView` that's showing part of an image. Is there a way that I can animate the `UIImageView` so that the image in it moves? So I wish to have my `UIImageView` stay in it's position but the image in it move. Any way of doing it?

Comment: UIImageView it's only container for UIImage

Comment: Read about core animation and core graphics.

Comment: @Anton If I knew which part I should read I wouldn't be hear asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but the way you usually do this is by adding your `UIImageView` to a `UIScrollView`. Make the scroll view as large as you want the displayed image to be but make its `contentSize` and the image view in it as large as they need to be.

Now you can animate the scroll position of the scroll view to smoothly animate the image position / crop.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm at work and can't test it, but it does look like a great solution :)